# Magento EE upgrade from 2.1.11 to 2.3.2 Error

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, upgrade

I have upgraded the Magento version from Magento EE 2.2.11 to 2.3.2 via composer after the upgrade is completed I am running the below command

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I am getting the below error.

> Notice: Undefined index: column in
>   /var/www/html/TTM/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php
>   on line 196

Any answer?